# Exception has occurred: ModuleNotFoundError No module named 'influxdb'

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, virtualenv, influxdb

I'm maintaining a python file, which contains the following code. It worked fine before, but when I modify the code and debug, it occurs an error, which says "Exception has occurred: ModuleNotFoundError
No module named 'influxdb'".

```
from influxdb import InfluxDBClient
```

[image]

I've already checked whether I installed the package or not, but still not worked.

[image]

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Is your VSCode installation (not only the terminal within) aware of the `backend` venv you installed your requirement into?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have selected the 'backend' venv in VSCode as well, otherwise it'll be validating your code with the global Python packages.

You have a shortcut for it in the lower right-corner (in my case the venv is called 'venv' and contains a Python 3.10.10 as opposed to the global Python 3.11).
Example below

[VS Code Python environment selector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U0WlV.png)